# How to pass xpath value read from XML file to driver.findElement(By.xpath(variableName))

Tags: java, xml, selenium, xpath

I am reading Xpath value from XML file using `JAXB` and then passing that value to 
xpath argument:

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath(variableName));
e.click();
```

where `variableName` is a String variable, and its value has been read from the XML.

It is not working. But the following code is working:

```
String variableName = "//*[@id=\"treemenu1\"]/li[48]";
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath(variableName));
e.click();
```

Can any one tell me where i am making mistake?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Before click on webElement print what value is returned by XML as below:
System.out.println(variableName);
WebElement e=driver.findElement(By.xpath(variableName)); 
e.click();

And verify is it matching with what you are referring "//*[@id=\"treemenu1\"]/li[48]"

Comment: Yes, I tested that...it is matching...

Comment: so are you fetching from xml  then assigning it to` variableName` as `String variableName = valuefromXML();` plus post result of `System.out.println(variableName); `